# how to give a group structure

Tags: abstract-algebra

suppose you have two sets $G_1$ and $G_2$ 
with same cardinality

in $G_2$ you have the group structure
and there is a bijective map from 
$G_1$ to $G_2$
this is just a set map.
can we define a binary operation
on $G_1$
with the help of binary operation on $G_2$
so that $G_1$ also become a group?

Comment: This is a standard "transport of structure" argument. Conceptually, $G_1$ and $G_2$ are the "same" for all (non-set-theoretic) intents and purposes because they are in bijection.

Comment: Yes. If $f:G_1\to G_2$ is the given bijection, then letting $\circ_1$ be defined by $x\circ_1 y=f^{-1}(f(x)\circ_2 f(y))$ gives you a group structure on $G_1$.

Comment: but how I will be sure that $x._1y$ is in $G_1$?I mean closoure property holds?

Comment: I don't see your problem. $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are in $G_2$, so $f(x)circ_2 f(y)$ is in $G_2$, since $G_2$ has a group structure. And since $f$ is bijective, $f^{-1}(f(x)circ_2 f(y))$ is a unique element in $G_1$.

Comment: The magic words are [transport of structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT: There’s really only one reasonable thing to try, and it works. Let $f:G_1\to G_2$ be your bijection, and let $\cdot$ be the group operation in $G_2$. You want to use $f$ to define a group operation $\odot$ on $G_1$. Suppose that $x,y\in G_1$; what would $x\odot y$ have to be in order for $f$ to be a group isomorphism?